# is it possible to add a link in google's datatable?

Tags: javascript, datatable

is it possible to add a link in google's datatable?

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#DataTable, http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/examples.html#table_example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is possible. Google's DataTable has a property: `allowHtml`:

```
table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, allowHtml: true});
```